# ClassCastException leer ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un clase Cliente implements Serializable. Después tengo que utilizar la siguiente clase Lista.

```
public class Lista{
private Object [] tabla;

public Lista(){
    tabla=new Object[0];
}
```

Después en la clase Principal tengo el siguiente método:

```
public static void readFile(){
    try{
        ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(s));
        listado=(Lista)ois.readObject();
        
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado.");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.out.println(cnfe);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.getMessage();
    }
}
```

En esta clase principal tengo un atributo: static Lista listado;
Entonces tengo problemas en las siguientes tres opciones que he probado:

1. Object obj=ois.readObject();
   listado=(Lista)obj;
2. listado=(Lista)ois.readObject();
3. listado=(Lista)(Object)ois.readObject();
   A ver si alguien me puede hechar una mano para ver como puedo leer el archivo. Quiero resolverlo sin genéricos todavía.
   Saludos a todos. Gracias.
   Como respuesta a Ruslan López le pongo la clase Cliente

   public class Cliente implements Serializable{
   private int id;
   private String nombre;
   private String telefono;

   public Cliente(int id, String nombre, String telefono) {
   this.id = id;
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.telefono = telefono;
   }
   }

Y le añado métodos de la clase Lista

```
public void insertarFinal(Object nuevo){
    tabla=Arrays.copyOf(tabla,tabla.length+1);
    tabla[tabla.length-1]=nuevo;
}

public void insertarFinal(Lista otraLista){
    int tamanoInicial=tabla.length;
    tabla=Arrays.copyOf(tabla,tabla.length+otraLista.tabla.length);
    System.arraycopy(otraLista.tabla, 0, tabla, tamanoInicial, otraLista.tabla.length);
}

public void insertar(int posicion,Object nuevo){
    tabla=Arrays.copyOf(tabla,tabla.length+1);
    System.arraycopy(tabla, posicion, tabla, posicion+1, tabla.length-posicion-1);
    tabla[posicion]=nuevo;
}

public Object eliminar(int indice){
    Object eliminado=null;
    
    if(indice>=0 && indice<tabla.length){
        eliminado=tabla[indice];
        for(int i=indice+1; i<tabla.length; i++){
            tabla[i-1]=tabla[i];
        }
        tabla=Arrays.copyOf(tabla,tabla.length-1);
    }
    return eliminado;
}

public Object get(int indice){
    Object resultado=null;
    if(indice>=0 && indice<tabla.length){
        resultado=tabla[indice];
    }
    return resultado;
}

public int buscar(Object claveBusqueda){
    int indice=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<tabla.length && indice==-1; i++){
        if(tabla[i].equals(claveBusqueda)){
            indice=i;
        }
    }
    return indice;
}
```

Lo único que intento es leer y escribir en fichero clientes.txt
Gracias

Comment: no se puede reproducir tu problema sin el contenido del archivo, considera editar tu pregunta y agregarlo

Comment: Gracias por responder Ruslan López. He puesto un poco más de código. Creía que no hacía falta. Sobre la respuesta mía de que ya lo he resuelto, no es cierto, estoy en ello. Espero te sirva lo añadido.

Comment: Se aprecia mucho que agregues detalles, te invito a leer el articulo [mcve] que te ayudara a obtener mejores respuestas  en esta comunidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

ya lo he resuelto.
He creado un array de Cliente:

```
Cliente[] clientes;
```

y después en el método readFile he puesto:

```
clientes=(Cliente[])ois.readObject();//ClassCastException
        for(int i=0;i<clientes.length;i++){
            listado.insertarFinal(clientes[i]);
        }
```